The texts from my JSON file won't show up on screen after using scrollview and listitem function
Please help me. I tried using ScrollView and MDListItem to display a series of text from my json file into the "DICTIONARY" screen. However, my program for the dictionary screen shows a blank screen and a left arrow button only.
THIS IS MY PY FILE
from kivymd.app import MDApp 
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.uix.floatlayout import MDFloatLayout
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.core.window import Window
Window.clearcolor = (1, 1, 1, 1)
Window.size = (350, 600)
import datetime
from kivy.metrics import dp
from datetime import date
from kivy.properties  import StringProperty
from kivymd.uix.behaviors import CommonElevationBehavior
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivymd.uix.screen import Screen 
import json
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivymd.uix.list import MDListItem
from kivy.uix.recycleview import RecycleView

#SCREEN FOR THE DICTIONARY
class Dict(RecycleView):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.data = []
        self.populate_list()

    def populate_list(self):
        for _ in range(50):
            item = MDListItem()
            with open('lol\\dictionary.json','r') as fh:
                dictionary = json.load(fh)
            self.item = ({'text':word} for word in list(dictionary.keys()))
            item.text = f"This is element number {_}"
            item.text_color = (1, 0, 0, 1)  # Set text color to red (RGBA)
            self.data.append({'viewclass': 'MDListItem', 'text': item.text})
        container = self.parent.ids.container
        container.clear_widgets()  # Clear existing widgets
        container.add_widget(self)  # Add Dict instance to MDList

# Screen for to-dos
class Todos(CommonElevationBehavior, MDFloatLayout):
    title = StringProperty()
    description = StringProperty()

class Notes(CommonElevationBehavior, MDFloatLayout):
    title = StringProperty()
    description = StringProperty()

class Base(FloatLayout):
    pass

class DoNote(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        global screen_manager
        screen_manager = ScreenManager()
        screen_manager.add_widget(Builder.load_file("kv_files\\layout.kv"))
        screen_manager.add_widget(Builder.load_file("kv_files\\dictionary.kv"))
        screen_manager.add_widget(Builder.load_file("kv_files\\todo_list.kv"))
        screen_manager.add_widget(Builder.load_file("kv_files\\add_todo.kv"))
        screen_manager.add_widget(Builder.load_file("kv_files\\note_screen.kv"))
        screen_manager.add_widget(Builder.load_file("kv_files\\add_note.kv"))
        return screen_manager  # Instantiate Base class
    

    def dictionary_search(self, title, description):
       screen_manager.get_screen("dictionary_screen").dictionary_list.add_widget(Dict(title=title))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    DoNote().run()

THIS IS THE KV FILE FOR THE BUTTONS
#:import get_color_from_hex kivy.utils.get_color_from_hex

MDScreen:
    name: "main_screen"
    md_bg_color: get_color_from_hex('#bebebeff')
    MDFloatLayout:
        MDLabel:
            id: title
            halign: 'center'
            markup: True
            text: "[size=50][b]DoNote[/b][/size]"
            pos_hint: {'y': .35}
            text_color : get_color_from_hex('#7f2f00ff')
    Button:
        text: 'Dictionary'
        size_hint: .50, .08
        background_color: get_color_from_hex('#7f2f00ff')
        font_size: "20sp"
        color: 1,1,1,1
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5, 'center_y':0.7}
        on_release:
            root.manager.transition.direction = "up"
            root.manager.current = "dictionary_screen"
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgb: get_color_from_hex('#f8ffccff')

THIS IS THE KV FILE FOR THE DICTIONARY SCREEN
#:import get_color_from_hex kivy.utils.get_color_from_hex

<Dict>
    elevation: 3 
    md_bg_color: get_color_from_hex('#ffcfb2ff')
MDScreen:
    name: 'dictionary_screen'
    MDIconButton:
        icon: "arrow-left"
        user_font_size: "40sp"
        pos_hint: {'center_y': .96}
        text_color: get_color_from_hex('#7f2f00ff')
        on_release:
            root.manager.transition.direction = "down"
            root.manager.current = 'main_screen'
    MDBoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        MDBoxLayout:
            padding: 30
            orientation: "vertical"
            MDScrollView:
                MDList:
                    id: container
                    theme_text_color: "Custom"
                    text_color: 1, 0, 0, 1

THIS IS MY JSON FILE
{
     "anopheles" : "A genus of mosquitoes which are secondary hosts of the malaria parasites, and whose bite is the usual, if not the only,
 means of infecting human beings with malaria. Several species are
 found in the United States. They may be distinguished from the
 ordinary mosquitoes of the genus Culex by the long slender palpi,
 nearly equaling the beak in length, while those of the female Culex
 are very short. They also assume different positions when resting,
 Culex usually holding the body parallel to the surface on which it
 rests and keeping the head and beak bent at an angle, while Anopheles
 holds the body at an angle with the surface and the head and beak in
 line with it. Unless they become themselves infected by previously
 biting a subject affected with malaria, the insects cannot transmit
 the disease.",
     "uniclinal" : "See Nonoclinal.",
     "sarong" : "A sort of petticoat worn by both sexes in Java and the Malay Archipelago. Balfour (Cyc. of India)",
     "turcoman" : "1. A member of a tribe of Turanians inhabiting a region east of the Caspian Sea. 2. A Turcoman carpet. Turcoman carpet
 or rug, a kind of carpet or rug supposed to be made by the
 Turcomans.",
     "corrugator" : "A muscle which contracts the skin of the forehead into wrinkles.",
     "self-murder" : "Suicide." }


did you run in console/terminal to see if it gives some error message?

you could reduce code because it is hard to run it.
